# Does increasing the size of a weight bar diameter help prevent tendinopathies?

Tags: tendinopathy, prevention, epicondylitis, weightlifting

There exist a many products designed to increase the size of a weight bar diameter: https://www.google.com/search?q=Fat+Gripz

[image]

Does increasing the size of a weight bar diameter help prevent tendinopathies?

I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies (medial or lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but from what I've read of products like that it seems like it might do the opposite since it increases load on the muscles. Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: @CareyGregory https://sportstherapyandrehab.com/2014/08/28/grip-size-elbow-problems/#.XGI8cFVKjYU " Playing with a grip that’s too small, on the other hand, can be quite dangerous, as it requires more gripping strength to keep the racquet from turning in your hand."